# Sufficient conditions for constancy of regression

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be dependent positive random variables. If I assume constancy of regression: $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=d$$
If possible, my aim is to find sufficient conditions for the Covariance to have if and only if statement with above.

If $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ then no linear relationship exist but that does not imply a constant regression (as it might have different dependence structure).

Now if I let $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y|Y>c)=0,\ \forall c\ge0$. Using the definition of the covariance and conditional expectations I get:
$$\left(\int_c^\infty f_Y(l)\ dl\right)\left(\int_c^\infty \mathbb{E}[XY|Y=k]f_Y(k)\ dk\right)=\left(\int_c^\infty \mathbb{E}[Y|Y=l]f_Y(l)\ dl\right)\left(\int_c^\infty \mathbb{E}[X|Y=k]f_Y(k)\ dk\right)$$
If I differentiate w.r.t $c$ I get:
$$\int_c^\infty\left(\mathbb{E}[XY|Y=l]+\mathbb{E}[XY|Y=c]\right)f_Y(l)\ dl=\int_c^\infty\left(\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\mathbb{E}[X|Y=l]+\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=l]\mathbb{E}[X|Y=c]\right)f_Y(l)\ dl$$
But this does not imply $$\mathbb{E}[XY|Y=l]+\mathbb{E}[XY|Y=c]=\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=c]\mathbb{E}[X|Y=l]+\mathbb{E}[Y|Y=l]\mathbb{E}[X|Y=c],\ \forall l\ge c \ge0$$ as we have a dependency on $c$ inside of the integral.

If I consider $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y|c_1<Y<c_2)=0,\ \forall c_2>c_1\ge0$ by splitting the integral and differentiating w.r.t $c_1$ and then $c_2$ I get the above implication with $c_1=c$ and $c_2=l$. but will it give a constant regression?

What if I consider $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y|\min(c_1,c_2)<Y< \max(c_1,c_2))=0, \forall c_1,c_2 \ge0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the general definition of conditional expectation $E(X|Y)=d$ iff $EXI_{Y \in A} =dP(Y \in A)$ for all Borel sets $A$. This is true iff the same equation holds for every interval $A$. Hence a necessary and sufficient condition is $cov(X,I_{a<Y<b})=0$ whenever $a<b$.

Comment: You are right. So if we consider $\mathbb{Cov}(X,Y|a<Y<b)=0\ \forall b>a\ge 0$ we can arrive at the form above and letting $f(a)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=a]$ we get $f(a)=f(b)\ \forall b>a$ which implies $f(b)=f(0)=d \ \forall b>0$ as required.

Comment: Do you know if $\mathrm{Cov}(X,\ \mathbb{I}_{Y>a})=0\ \forall a\ge 0$ gives a  regression relation (non constant)? Since it only gives information about the tail events (only tail borel sets) I want to know if  a regression relation is possible.